# Replace word when stand alone

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
select last_name as lastname from table
```

and I want to change the "as" keyword to capital (for the rest of my script to run properly), but only when its alone.

when i use this script:

```
$toupper = str_replace(array("select","from","where","order by", "group by", "as"),
                  array("SELECT","FROM","WHERE","ORDER BY", "GROUP BY","AS"),$query);
```

It will also change the other strings that have "as".
so it becomes this:

```
SELECT lASt_name AS lAStname FROM table
```

how can i replace the stand alone keyword "as" to "AS"?

Comment: Just replace `" as "` with `" AS "`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not working with a linebreak behind "as" though. :(

Comment: Counter question: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @ClémentMalet . . . Are you really dealing with code that puts the `as` on a separate line with no spaces before it?  That is awful formatting.  The code should be fixed to be readable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not, some people do (could) indent their query that way. (And well, I guess `as` was an exemple, the title says words, so it could be `from`, and `SELECT x\nFROM y\nWHERE ...` doesn't seem terrible to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use almost the exact code you currently have.

Since `AS` statement always has a space before and after it, just modify `str_replace` slightly to have a space before and after `as` and `AS`, like so:

```
$toupper = str_replace(array("select","from","where","order by", "group by", " as ",),array("SELECT","FROM","WHERE","ORDER BY", "GROUP BY"," AS "),$query);
```

The result is:

`SELECT last_name AS lastname FROM table`

This way you can keep the code you have virtually identical.

Comment: wauw, that i didn't think of this... feel so stupid now.
Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 3):

You should a regular expression to match whole words only:

```
$toupper = preg_replace("/\bas\b/", "AS", $query);
```

Using a word boundary before and after the word is more effective than using a space at the same positions because it matches all non-word characters like space, line-break, hyphen and so on. You may read about the anchor `\b` [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).